# jscrollpane not working on jtable in swing application

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I am working on swing application in that I use the `jTable` and `jScrollpane` now my problem with this is I add multiple tables in one scrollpane and the scroll work fine on other then table area but it not work when the cursor is on table area.

The space between two tables the scroll work fine but on table area it does not work.
any one have any idea about my problem? so please give me answer very fast...
thanks in advance...

Comment: Correct your sentences for getting answers,your problem is not at all clear in this question...

Comment: you can't add multiple components to a scrollPane (aka: it's main viewport) - so your description of "working" can't really be. Consider showing some sample code (best: an SSCCE) to demonstrate what you are expecting vs experiencing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added multiple tables without using scrollpane in one panel and then added the panel in to scrollpane.By this way my problem solved.

The scrollpane you need to add because of without adding high level component(scrollpane) the header does not added to the table.

you can use the under give format to add header without using scrollpane

```
//initializes the table
 JTable table=new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
//add table header to any component(panel)
component.add(table.getTableHeader());
//add table to any component(panel)
component.add(tableRelatedProducts);
```

Answer (score 2):

*there are to much complicated code so i do not shown here* ... Euh, a panel containing multiple tables in a scrollpane. Where is the complicated part. See below for an SSCCE which does exactly that.

```
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class TableTest {
  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        JFrame testFrame = new JFrame( "Test" );

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel( new BorderLayout(  ) );
        JPanel tablePanel = new JPanel(  );
        tablePanel.setLayout( new BoxLayout( tablePanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS ) );
        addTableToPanel( tablePanel );
        addTableToPanel( tablePanel );
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( tablePanel );
        contentPane.add( scrollPane );
        testFrame.setContentPane( contentPane );

        testFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation( WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        testFrame.pack();
        testFrame.setVisible( true );
      }
    } );
  }

  private static void addTableToPanel( JPanel aTablePanel ) {
    JTable table = createTable();
    aTablePanel.add( table.getTableHeader() );
    aTablePanel.add( table );
  }

  private static JTable createTable(){
    return new JTable( new DefaultTableModel( new Object[][]{new Object[]{"Data1-1", "Data1-2"}, new Object[]{"Data2-1", "Data2-2"}},
                                                      new Object[]{"Column1", "Column2"}) );
  }
}
```

Note that I do not have a problem scrolling when the cursor is over the table. So we need more information then is available in your question.

Probably, if you create an SSCCE (or adjust this one) which can reproduce your problem you will discover the problematic piece of code.

Comment: I got the answer but the problem is how to add table without adding table in to jScrollpane? if i add without jScrollpane the header does not display. thanks for your reply

Comment: See my code snippet where I add the header manually. This is explained in the [Table tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#show)